# Attachment in Android

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I'm doing simple voice recording application. In my application, after the voice recording the file will be send to someone through mail using `Intent`

I've fetch the file path properly and it's also attached. But, the file size is 0 bytes when i receive the file to my mail. What am missing? And, also, my file size is didn't shown when sending email?

Comment: we need to see some code to help you, it all depends on that (like, how are you using the intent, how are sending it).

Comment: @TryTryAgain See here - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bVtCuHnM

Comment: I must be blind. I can't see anything of an email going out with the saved audiofile.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to give this - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QJ8RbXG5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this by my own. Like -

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{emailTo});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);
//has to be an ArrayList
 ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
 //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
 for (String file : filePaths)
 {
     File fileIn = new File(file);
     Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
     uris.add(u);
 }
 emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
 emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Thanks for reply you all.

Answer (score 2):

I think the URL is not proper so that it is attaching a 0KB file

Use below line to attached file

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + path));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have the path of the file in `savedUri`. Now just a question of attaching to email. Try this:

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    emailIntent.setType("audio/amr");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"ab@xyz.com"});  
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "xyz");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:/"+ savedUri));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sent"));
```

Comment: Changed wav to amr. I think the same code should work for amr.

Answer (score 1):

i've done for send any file from SD card with mail attachment..

```
Intent sendEmail= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       sendEmail.setType("rar/image");
       sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new        
                 File("/mnt/sdcard/download/abc.rar")));
                 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmail, "Email:"));
```